# Не работает SQL запрос с кириллицей

Tags: php, mysql

Необходимо сделать поиск по таблице согласно данным с пост запроса

```
  $query = "SELECT * FROM vhod WHERE `otdel` LIKE '%".$_POST['compare']."%' OR 
    `number` LIKE '%".$_POST['compare']."%' OR 
        `sname` LIKE '%".$_POST['compare']."%' OR 
                `Time` LIKE '%".$_POST['compare']."%'";
```

Когда строка содержит латинские символы, то запрос работает на ура, когда ввожу данные на кириллице, то запрос не выполняется. Проверял, что приходит в POST запросе через echo(), там все правильно. Поэтому предполагаю, что дело в условии, только вот что..?

Comment: А с кодировками у вас там все нормально, кодировка базы при подключении установлена такой же в какой данные приходят

Comment: А что значит "запрос не выполняется"? Выполняется, но пустой результат выводит?

Comment: После подключения я ставлю кодировку UTF8. mysqli_set_charset($link,"utf8"); Такую же как и в БД.

Comment: $result = mysqli_query($link,$query) or die("Запрос ошибочный");
Под "запрос не выполняется" я имел ввиду, что появляется сообщение "Запрос ошибочный"

Comment: Причем, если, к примеру, в запросе указать, что мы ищем данные только по одному столбцу, то все работает, как с кириллицей, так и с латинскими, но когда я добавляю несколько условий, то происходит такая беда.

Comment: В посте могут быть кавычки или еще что-то ломающее запрос

Comment: Нет, там все нормально. Все таки думаю, что дело в кодировке условий, когда запрос берет поле `otdel`, а там название отдела на кириллице, то " запрос ошибочный", а если,например, IT, то все нормально. Не могу понять, как сопоставить кодировки.

Comment: А что у вас в базе написано, какая кодировка для текстовых полей таблицы?

Comment: Пробовали каждый POST-параметр обернуть в mysql_escape_string? `number` LIKE '%".mysql_escape_string($_POST['compare'])."%' OR